# How to use remote theme in Jekyll project with Gitlab Pages repo?

Tags: gitlab, jekyll, jekyll-theme, gitlab-pages

I am using linux/firefox and I'm having an issue where a jekyll theme does not work when using `remote_theme:` inside the `.config.yml` of a Jekyll project kept in a GitLab pages repo. If I clone the theme `just-the-docs` (https://pmarsceill.github.io/just-the-docs/) locally, it works fine when `theme:` is used in the `.config.yml`. However, when using an example of a remote theme as written by the same author `pmarsceill/jtd-remote`, and adding `remote_theme:` instead of `theme:`, I get the same issue. The theme does not take effect.

I use `jtd-remote` as an example which gives the same error, though, my goal is to get `just-the-docs` working as a remote theme.

```
Clone 'https://github.com/pmarsceill/jtd-remote'
Add url to _config.yml.
Add index.md to top level.
Add to GitLab repo and configure pages.
Browse to repo url on 4000, theme does not take effect.
```

When using `just-the-docs`, my `.config.yml` appears as follows:

```
# Site settings
title: My site Test
description: "Testing"
baseurl: "/"
url: "https://mysite.gitlab.io"

color_scheme: "dark"
search_enabled: false

# Build settings
remote_theme: pmarsceill/just-the-docs
#remote_theme: "pmarsceill/just-the-docs@v0.3.3"

plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-remote-theme
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-mermaid
  - jekyll-spaceship
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a public repo and GitHub Pages URL demonstrating the issue you could share? Also, `baseurl` should generally be blank, or a path that starts with a leading slash (e.g. `baseurl:` or `baseurl: /docs`)

Comment: Well, that's the thing. It appears to work in GitHub, however, I'm trying to do remote themes in GitLab. The theme I'm trying to make remote on GitLab is ... https://github.com/pmarsceill/just-the-docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab doesn't support remote themes for Jekyll.